# Some words “want” to be plural and some other ones “want” to be singular. Why?

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, programming

This question is for people who write documents related to computer programming.

I am currently working on a style guide related to one programming language. There are a lot of examples and descriptions. Of course, I am trying to be consistent in all possible aspects.

One of these aspects is pluralization.

As I discovered, when I write about things like "ternary operator", "LF" (line feed, U+000A character), or the empty string, it is more natural to use singular form. That is, when I talk e.g. about the empty string or a ternary operator, I refer to the Platonic **entity** instead of its instances.

I write this:

> Don't use the ternary operator. It's too confusing for novice developers in your team.

Not this:

> Don't use ternary operators. They are too confusing for novice developers in your team.

On the other hand, when I write about things like spaces between words, commas, dots/periods, it's more natural to use plural form.

I write this:

> Use spaces the same way as in normal writing. For example, don't add a space before a comma, but add it after.

Not this:

> Use the space the same way as in normal writing. For example, don't add a space before a comma, but add it after.

For what reason I write it so? Is it something very personal (and other people would not probably say it in such a way) or there are some real reasons for it which I follow instinctively?

Comment: And it's *words* ***want***, not *wants*. (Unless you had meant it to be taken humorously.)

Comment: Are there any other "characters / symbols" apart from "space" that don't naturally accept being referenced by the definite article? I suspect it's just a quirk of the fact that "space" isn't *really* a "character" - it's more *the **absence** of a character,* and much of the time we can't even tell how many spaces there actually are at any given position within a written text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have the same issue with quotation marks. It is very unnatural to me to refer to `"` (U+0022) in singular form.

Comment: And the same is true for commas and periods.

Comment: Well... One idea could be that spaces, dots/periods, commas, semicolons, quotation marks are so familiar to us and so common in our everyday life that we treat them as individual physical objects. Operators, the line feed character, and the empty string are less familiar to us and not so common in our everyday life, and thus we treat them as abstractions.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but if by "the ternary operator", you mean something like `?:` in `a ? b : c`, [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:): "Although many ternary operators are possible, the conditional operator is so common, and other ternary operators so rare, that the conditional operator is commonly referred to as *the* ternary operator."

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1) The remark about spaces relates to whitespace, which might sometimes be several spaces, tabs, or line-breaks. The writer is thinking of single, isolated uses of the ternary operator. 2)  As regards spacing, styles vary in the amount of space used. But with the ternary operator, it's all-or-nothing. The writer is thinking "Bill writes C. Bill uses the ternary operator. This confuses novices. Don't be like Bill. Don't use the ternary operator."